# Pausing Teamcity builds that are running

Tags: teamcity

I would like to have Teamcity build configuration that currently has 3 build steps:

1. Build an artifact to perform tests on & install on remote server
2. Kick off long running test job on remote server
3. ***Pause build awaiting external event (i.e. remote job finishing)***
4. Retrieve results and record the report

I have had a look through the documentation and I can see how I can pause (***step 3***) the entire build configuration (which stops any additional builds running) ... but not just a single running build.

The Step 2 script that is running the external job has the various parameters passed to it, so that it can issue a REST call back to the teamcity server to resume the build job.

Basically I don't want to tie up a build agent waiting the entire hour the test takes to run.

I have googled and everything I can find points me at pausing the build configuration.

I am currently having to look at splitting the build configuration into two. The first will kick of the test job and finish. Then when the external test job finishes it will call teamcity to start a second job to retrieve and store the reports. But that feels disconnected to me in that I will not be able to show a single job with build/test/report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment (TeamCity v 2018.1) there is no direct way to pause the build, release the build agent, and later resume the execution.

What you described is the recommended workaround.

Also, please watch/vote for related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-30777